# mechanic can't reproduce trouble when car is at shop... need to record OBD data when problem occurs while driving

Tags: car, obd-ii, diagnostics, intermittent-problems

I brought my car in for servicing, but the mechanic can't reproduce the problem. I want to log OBD data as the problem occurs.  I would then provide this captured data with the car when it goes back to the shop.

My question is: if this can be done using a cheap OBD reader like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011NSX27A) (or something similar in price) and a Play Store app on my phone, what do I need to know in order to find a reader and app for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The reader should work fine, but you'll need to ensure the software you use is what will do the trick. I'm not sure if an app (Android or iOS) will work. Your best bet would most likely be to get a corded OBDII port to USB adapter, then find software for a laptop to get the live data you need. I mean, you could check apps like Torque Pro or the other apps listed to see if it can record the live data or not. If it will, then you're golden.

Comment: Looking at some of the apps, I've seen the term "freeze". Is this the term they use to mean record live data?  Is this just one "frame" of info?  My concern is that if I tap "freeze" at the wrong moment it won't get the data I need.  I think of recording live data as a whole stream of individual frames. This way whatever frame it is that is useful will be saved. I have no idea if any of this makes sense because I don't know anything about what data is taken and how often, what format or whatever etc. I know a little about computers and electronics but nothing about cars! Hope I'm not being...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm pretty sure "freeze" means "freeze frame" or just a "spot in time".

Comment: Yeah, I think so too.  Anyway, I found a gizmo which says it can "Provide data playback, capture, and recording function" although that sounds like a feature of the app rather than the dongle.  So I'm ordering that one now and will sort out the details later.  Thanks for the help!  (oops, is saying "thank you" in comments a faux pas, or is that bad etiquette just in the actual question?  [nevermind, I'm just thinking out loud... I hope that's not a no-no! yikes!] )

Comment: As well as various cabled USB OBD2 scanners, I have a bluetooth one which connects to the Torque app on my Android phone. So I live record on my phone - works really well.

Comment: How do you record?  Does the Torque app have this feature, or do you need another app to record what appears on the screen?

Comment: Freeze frame is a snapshot that the ECU captures at the time of a fault. It displays the status of certain sensors like engine temp, RPM, etc. When the fault occured. It could be helpful in your case. Live data recording is the ECU recording actual status of sensors over a period of time. Like a movie.

Comment: Some dongles are very cheap and don't support what you want to do, but claim they do.  Others work pretty well.  Been down that road.  Last one worked well with Android app.